# Basic API in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, api, url

Let's assume I have a `Users` controller with a `returnjson` action. Say I want to create an API so when the client calls on that method, it would return the user's data to the client. For example:

https://www.example.com/returnjson?username&password

A get request would be made by JavaScript with that URL and than the rails would than return the user info in a JSON format. How would I got about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rails already has all of the machinery for this built into it.  see "2.2.9 Rendering JSON" in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: But how would I access the username and password parameters passed in by the get request

Comment: `params[:username]` and `params[:password]` should be equal to `bob` and `p4ssw0rd` for the link `/returnjson?username=bob&password=p4ssw0rd` -- also, it is not recommended to pass a password in a GET request, for obvious security reasons. Use POST instead ;-)

Comment: @MrYoshiji thanks for the response. One last question though. What would the routes look like? I dont think `resources :users` would be enough to get the parameters, or will it?

Comment: nope, `resources :users` will just provide the basic CRUD actions (create, retrieve, update, delete, which are respectively the controller's actions create, index, update, delete (and the show action)). In your case, you need a custom action that will return json. If you want to call it `returnjson` (which is not very consistent IMO), you could do `post :returnjson, controller: 'controller_name#action_name'` to create a POST route to `/returnjson`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh i see, you only want to return the attributes requested in the parameters.  Sorry.

First of all, i would just us the `show` action for this rather than making a new action.  The purpose of `show` semantically is to return data for a single record, so it's the right action for this job.

Your parameters for the request aren't well structured - i would structure them like

https://www.example.com/users/123?required[]=username&required[]=password

which would give you

```
params = {:required => ["username", "password"]}
```

I would do it like so:

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html #default to standard 'render the show template'
    format.js #default to standard 'render .js file'  or whatever
    format.json do 
      #filter out the ones we want
      if params[:required]
        hash = @user.attributes.slice(params[:required])
      else
        hash = @user.attributes
      end
      #this will automatically call `.to_json` on the thing we pass to it (`hash` in this case)
      render json: hash
    end
  end
end
```

You can add extra security things in here, for example to limit the fields which you make accessable via the api.